# displyed date in specific format in extjs 4

Tags: extjs4

I have a grid which contains a column named  dateOfBirth

the type of this column is **date**

I have displayed this column in my web application but the data  of dateOfBirth is displyed in this format for example

**Wed, 10 Jun 2009 16:11:53 +0100**

my goal is to display this date in this format : **d/m/y**

I try with this code :

```
var testGrid1 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        id:'testGrid1 ',
        store: testGridStore,
        collapsible:true,

        columns: [

            {text: 'test1', flex: 1, sortable: true,   dataIndex: 'num_speech'},
            {text: 'test2', flex: 1, sortable: true,   dataIndex: 'dateOfBirth'}

            ],

        columnLines: true,
        anchor: '100%',
        height: 250,
        frame: true,
        margin: '0 5 5 5',


    });
```

as I have already said this code display the date of column in this format :  **Wed, 10 Jun 2009 16:11:53 +0100**

to resolve this problem I try without success with

```
{text: 'test1', flex: 1, sortable: true,   dataIndex: 'dateOfBirth',dateFormat: 'd/m/y'},
```

I have a model :

```
Ext.define('needUtilitesList', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {name: 'dateOfBirth', type: 'date',dateFormat: 'd/m/y'},
                    {name: 'num_speech', type: 'string'}

        ]
    });
```

but it dosen't display the correct result

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "type: 'date'," so

```
{type:'date', flex: 1, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'dateOfBirth', dateFormat: 'd/m/y'}
```

If you have a model, you can also specify the type for your dateOfBirth property there as well so the framework knows to load it as a date.

Comment: -1. That should be `xtype: 'datecolumn'`. Also, the property is `format`, not `dateFormat`.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been looking at Ext.data.Field last night.  Evan is right.  http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Date